# Django + DRF Create file from json value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a part of django+drf app that will create article models from the given JSON request. Example of request:

```
{
    "title":"title"
    "author":"author"
    "text":"possible huge amount of text"
    ...
}
```

Article model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=config.ARTICLE_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='articles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Date created', auto_now_add=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    text = models.FileField(upload_to='content/articles_storage/', null=True)
```

This data is processed by article serializer

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # content = serializers.CharField() ???
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        # fields = ['id','title','views','date_created','content']
        fields = ['id','title','views','date_created','text']
```

Serializer expects `text` field to be a file, however, it is gonna be plain text, so when the user makes a POST request to the server, I want the server to validate the text, create a file from this text, save it to the folder `content/article_storage`
When the user makes a GET request, I want the server to read that file and create a JSON response like above.
My question is what is the best way to do this? I definitely don't want to use django's TextField. Also I'm wondering if I actually need FieldFile, maybe it's better to store the text in a file with the name = article id?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use a `TextField`? Anyway, you'll need a custom serializer field to do this, look at [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields). You can create a `File` using the [`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) class and then assign it to your `FileField`. The other way round, you just read your [`FieldFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile).

Comment: @dirkgroten yes, custom field looks good, thank you. The reason why I prefer not using TextField is that I will use some custom algorithms for fast search designed to work with files, and I’m not sure how exactly TextField works under the hood if I use postgres as default db

Comment: Seen that django supports [full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) with postgreSQL? Might not be as fast as your search, but worth a try?

Comment: @dirkgroten, I can’t find any info about the time complexity of that search, that’s very important to me

Comment: If you add the document vector and index with a GIN index (auto-triggering update of the document vector), it's as fast as querying a column with a b-tree index.